# Connecting Iphone 5s to the raspberry Pi

Tags: camera

Is it possible to connect the Iphone 5s to the Raspberry Pi through a usb cable?
If I plug it in now it starts charging.

And when its connected, is it possible to give the telephone a command to make a picture and send it to the Raspberry Pi? And if that is possible, how can I make it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not an expert on iPhones, but I know these are very much locked down from what you can do from the outside. Does what you want work with the PC / MAC (using existing software)?

Comment: Hello and welcome -- What's objective? Screen sharing? Data transfration? Etc?